# PHP square brackets syntax

Tags: php

Given this code snippet:

```
$nodes[$record->nid]->group = $record->group;
```

I do not understand what the first part (to the left of the equals sign) means?

Thanks.

Comment: `$nodes` is an arrary. The name of one of its array keys is the _value_ of the object property `$record->nid`.  That key holds an object of some type, which has a property `->group`.

Comment: See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$nodes` is an array, and `$record->nid` is an index in that array. For this code to be valid, `$record->nid` must be either a string or an integer.

Calling `$nodes[$record->nid]` will return an object, that you are then calling `group` on.

Comment: Important to note that `$record->nid` must contain a _string_ or integer to be an array key.

Comment: good call, will update answer :)

Answer (score 3):

> I do not understand what the first part (to the left of the equals sign) means?

Breaking `$nodes[$record->nid]->group` apart:

- `$nodes` is an array of objects
- `$nodes[$record->nid]` accesses the element with a key of `$record->nid`
- `$nodes[$record->nid]->group` access the `group` property of the object (`$nodes[$record->nid]`)